# How do I open 'Google Settings' of an Android device programatically?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, google-settings

I want to access 'Google Settings' in Android programatically, is there any way I can do that using Intent?

`"com.google.android.gms.location.settings.GOOGLE_LOCATION_SETTINGS"` didn't work using Intent.